# Applications in ~/Applications not shown in Applications folder in dock

Tags: applications, dock, homebrew

I just noticed that `brew cask install` symlinks to `~/Applications`. This works fine, but the application item in my dock does not show apps from that folder. Is it supposed to work this way? I expected to have an aggregated view of `/Applications` and `~/Applications` in my dock.

Answer (score 2):

Each item in the dock is a single folder.

OS X does not have merged folder views except in Finder where there are Smart folders

However you could create a smart folder in Finder of Kind is Application and drag that to the Dock

Comment: Mh that's what I guessed. I will just symlink to /Applications then by myself.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to force `brew cask install` to create the links in the root Applications directory.

> - `--appdir=/my/path` changes the path where the symlinks to the applications (above) will be generated. This is commonly used to
>     create the links in the root Applications directory instead of the
>     home Applications directory by specifying `--appdir=/Applications`.
>     Default is `~/Applications`.
>
> To make these settings persistent, you might want to add the following
>   line to your `.bash_profile` or `.zshenv`:
>
> ```
> # Specify your defaults in this environment variable
> export HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS="--appdir=/Applications --caskroom=/etc/Caskroom"
> ```

Source: [How to Use Homebrew-cask](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/USAGE.md)